# Assign Ctrl+Y to Redo in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently having some trouble trying to assign any additional keybindings to the Normal Mode while using the VIM extension for VSCode. Any ideas on how to potentially rewrite the ctrl+y keybind back to the original default for VSCode? I've tried assigning various keys to Edit.Redo, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Have you unbound all other commands bound to ctrl+y?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Open VS Code & Go to `keyboard shortcuts`
- There will be a search bar at the top
- Type `redo` in the search bar. its might be  mapped to
  `shift+cmd+z` (Mac) or `shift+ ctrl+z` (windows)
- Double click on existing keyboard mapping
- A box will appear.
- Do not click or type anything, just use your keyboard and type `cmd+y` or `ctrl+y` and press Enter

Thats all.

More on my post with images [medium blog link](https://medium.com/@manvendrapsingh/unable-to-redo-in-vs-code-a181f418c1b9)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following -

1- Press crtl+shift+P and write `open keyboard shortcuts`

2- Press enter and search for Redo

you can then edit the shortcut using the edit button

Comment: This works for normal shortcuts, but when you have the extension VIM installed, there's a higher priority keybinding that overwrites ctrl+y